# Java - output text from file as keyboard emulation

Tags: java, io, inputstream, outputstream, keyboard-hook

If I had a file `numbers.txt` with the following string:

`*1222223* @4555556 !7888889! $19.99`

How would I go about reading that line, removing the symbols, and outputting it via keyboard emulation as follows:

`4555556 [TAB] 7888889 [TAB] [TAB] 1222223 [TAB] 19.99`

[TAB] being emulation for the TAB key as opposed to a literal string.

Of course, during the output, I do not know what the numbers are, or even what order those numbers are in originally. Think of the `*` `@` `!` and `$` symbols as placeholders for the location of these numbers, and I want to go from a `* @ ! $` input to a `@ ! * $` output.

Let me know if this isn't specific enough.

EDIT: I know absolutely nothing about Java. I do batch/shell scripting, HTML, CSS and some PHP. My question pertains to an action that my company needs to implement into a simple program but we are ill equipped with Java-Know-How.

Comment: tab can be added to a String using `\t` escape sequence. Logic for  parsing and ordering numbers is completely up to you.

Comment: Don't edit Closed into the title. If you feel the question is obsolete you can delete it yourself.

Comment: Can't delete it because there's an answer. And there are no right Flags to use to vote it to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding you, what you are looking for is something like this

http://gruimed.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-java-robot-to-type-text-strings.html

Edit: to read a file character by character, you can use this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Readfilecharacterbycharacter.htm

Given that, in the link first link with the robot example,there's a method

> private void typeChar(char c)

to translate each character into a keycode and type it using java.awt.Robot.  Exclude any non-necessary characters using conditionals in the typing logic and insert tabs using emulation in the robot with TAB's keycode, which is stored in java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB constant.

Comment: Adding extra information into main post for the "Assumption".

Comment: Thank you for the information. It may be a few days or weeks before it gets tested, but I'm pretty good at updating and voting on my questions.

Comment: Looks like management decided to not move forward with it so I will not be testing it. Thanks for the assistance however.